# $|| P ||\leq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection

Can somebody explain the final step why $ || P ||\leq 1$ here:
[https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pcma/1416340413](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQzKQ.png)

$P$ is a Projector and it self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

$$\|Px\|^2\le \|Px\|^2+\|Px-x\|^2=\|x\|^2$$ so $\|Px\|\le\|x\|$ which implies that $\|P\|\le 1$.